# Finding the $2n$ th derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}$ with repect to $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

We know that with repect to $x$,

\begin{align}
\left( \frac{1}{1-x^2 y^2} \right)^{(2n)} = 
\frac{(2n)!y^{2n}}{2 } \left(  \frac{1}{(1+xy)^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-xy)^{2n+1}} \right)
\end{align}

What about

\begin{align}
\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2 y^2} \right)^{(2n)} 
\end{align}

Comment: __Hint__ substitute $y\mapsto iy$

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is make this substitution $y = ik$, we can do this freely because the derivative is with respect to x not to y, and it is only a contsant.Then after this substitution we get

$$\left( \frac{1}{1+x^2 y^2} \right)^{(2n)}=\left( \frac{1}{1-x^2 k^2} \right)^{(2n)}
$$

Which, as you said, is equal to
$$\frac{(2n)!k^{2n}}{2 } \left(  \frac{1}{(1+xk)^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-xk)^{2n+1}} \right)
$$

Finally we just substitute $\frac{y}{i}=k$ and we obtain that 
for the derivative of a number with the form 4k we have
$$\frac{(2n)!y^{2n}}{2 } \left(  \frac{1}{(1+\frac{xy}{i})^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-\frac{xy}{i})^{2n+1}} \right)
$$
and for the derivative of a number with the form 4k+2 we have
$$\frac{-(2n)!y^{2n}}{2 } \left(  \frac{1}{(1+\frac{xy}{i})^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-\frac{xy}{i})^{2n+1}} \right)
$$
then  if we do not want i, we  only have to  add the two terms and apply the binomial theorem.

Comment: The function is a real valued one, so, can we make the $i$ disappear in the formula? Because in the end, there will be no $i$.

Comment: I did not find a form without $i$  now ,but I do not think that $i$ is an obstacle , What are you doing that you need a form without the imaginary unit?

Comment: Estimating maximum values for a function, and $i$ is getting in the way.

Comment: I thought a little more, you just have to use the binomial theorem

Comment: since the exponent is going to be odd, the terms with an odd exponent will be canceled and only the even that are real will be left because $i$ raised to 2 and 4 and successively is -1,1,-1...

Comment: Oh the k is a typo ,thst I just corrected thanks to your comment, but the sign comes from $\frac{1}{i^{2}}$

Comment: Thanks you for the advice

Comment: Just put the final result into the same fraction, and it will become more obvious it's real.

Comment: @BlasCasazza $(1/i)^{2n}$ equals sometimes $1$ :)

Comment: Maybe we can evaluate the $2n$ th derivative this way https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950916/finding-the-2n1-th-derivative-of-fracy2n1xy1-x2y2-with-respect-t and maybe the $i$ will vanish