# Writing $\frac{1}{(1+ixy)^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-ixy)^{2n+1}}$ in a way that is independent of $i$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

The function below is independent of $i$ for all integer $n \geq 0$.
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{(1+ixy)^{2n+1}} +\frac{1}{(1-ixy)^{2n+1}} = \frac{(1-ixy)^{2n+1}+(1+ixy)^{2n+1}}{(1+x^2y^2)^{2n+1}}
\end{align}

The denominator is independent of $i$, so I think should be possible to write $(1-ixy)^{2n+1} + (1+ixy)^{2n+1}$ as a function that does not depend on $i$.

Something somewhat close is $(1-xy)^{2n+1} + (1+xy)^{2n+1}$.

$x,y$ are real valued.

This doubt arised after making this question:

[Finding the $2n$ th derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}$ with repect to $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969922/finding-the-2n-th-derivative-of-frac11x2y2-with-repect-to-x)

I'm trying to estimate a maximum value for a function and the $i$ is getting in the way.

Maybe we can evaluate the $2n$ th derivative of $1/(1+x^2y^2)$ with respect to $x$ in a similar way to  [Finding the $2n+1$ th derivative of $\frac{y^{2n+1}xy}{1-x^2y^2}$ with respect to $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950916/finding-the-2n1-th-derivative-of-fracy2n1xy1-x2y2-with-respect-t)

and $i$ will vanish.

Comment: The best you can do is use the binomial theorem to get the numerator and cancel out the terms that can be canceled. The odd terms cancel.

Comment: Suggested to clarify what is meant by "independent of $i$'. Is $i$ the complex unity in this case? Is is a real-valued scalar? Do mean to say that the complex expression is real? Or that whatever value you attribute to $x$ the function evaluates to the same result for fixed $x$ and $y$? (if the latter was the case you could just set $1=0$.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1} = i$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $1+ixy = re^{it}$ in polar form.  Then your expression becomes

$$\frac{(e^{-it})^{2n+1} + (e^{it})^{2n+1}}{r^{2n+1}}$$

$$= \frac{2\cosh (2n+1)t}{r^{2n+1}}$$

$$= \frac{2\cosh ( (2n+1)\tan^{-1}(xy))}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2y^2}\right)^{2n+1}}.$$

Comment: Why the $2n+2$ in the final line instead of $2n+1$ ?

Comment: @Pinteco  Just a typo.

Answer (score 2):

It is like $(1-a)^m+(1+a)^m$, where $m$ is odd. The coefficients with odd power of a will cancel out while those of with even power will add up. $ixy$ with even power will be independent of $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=(1+ixy)^{2n+1}$, then

$\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{\overline{z}}=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{|z|^2}=2 \frac{Re(z)}{|z|^2} \in \mathbb R$.