# The $2n$ th derivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}$ with respect to $x$ in a way that does not require the imaginary unit.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

I wanted to know what is the $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}$ of
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x^2y^2}
\end{align}
But the answer I got from another post was a function relaying on the imaginary unit $i^2=-1$, and I wonder if we can find the $2n$ th derivative in a different way.

Comment: What post are you referring to? If possible, the $\mathrm i$ could be avoided after certain algebraic manipulations.

Comment: In this post is the derivative with the $i$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969922/finding-the-2n-th-derivative-of-frac11x2y2-with-repect-to-x after some manipulations we get the function $\frac{2\cosh ( (2n+2)\tan^{-1}(xy))}{\left(\sqrt{1+x^2y^2}\right)^{2n+1}}.$ But this functions is terrible to work with...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't double checked the simplifications between steps. So please verify as you read. If there is a mistake, I can correct and I believe the approach is still going to work out.

When you have a composite function $f\circ g$, its $n$th derivative is given by [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula). That formula looks bad, but here I would take $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $g(x)=y^2x^2$, and that means that third derivatives and higher of $g$ are zero. So the formula becomes

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=\sum\frac{(2n)!}{m_1!m_2!2^{m_2}}f^{(m_1+m_2)}\mathopen{}\left(y^2x^2\right)\mathclose{}\cdot \left(2y^2x\right)^{m_1}\left(2y^2\right)^{m_2}$$

where the sum is over all nonnegative $(m_1,m_2)$ with $m_1+2m_2=2n$. Some simplifications:

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=\sum\frac{(2n)!2^{m_1}x^{m_1}y^{2(m_1+m_2)}}{m_1!m_2!}f^{(m_1+m_2)}\mathopen{}\left(y^2x^2\right)\mathclose{}$$

Since $f(x)=(1+x)^{-1}$, then $f^{(N)}(x)=(-1)^NN!(1+x)^{-1-N}$. So the above is:

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=\sum\frac{(2n)!2^{m_1}x^{m_1}y^{2(m_1+m_2)}}{m_1!m_2!}(-1)^{m_1+m_2}(m_1+m_2)!\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{1+m_1+m_2}}$$

which is simpler as:

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=(2n)!\sum(2x)^{m_1}\left(-y^2\right)^{(m_1+m_2)}\binom{m_1+m_2}{m_1}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{1+m_1+m_2}}$$

Now the sum is still over all nonnegative $(m_1,m_2)$ with $m_1+2m_2=2n$. These pairs are easy to index. $m_2$ can range from $0$ to $n$, and then $m_1=2n-2m_2$. So we have:

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=(2n)!\sum_{m_2=0}^{n}(2x)^{2n-2m_2}\left(-y^2\right)^{(2n-m_2)}\binom{2n-m_2}{m_2}\frac{1}{\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{1+2n-m_2}}$$

Simplified a little as:

$$\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\frac{1}{1+y^2x^2}=\frac{(2n)!(2xy^2)^{2n}}{\left(1+x^2y^2\right)^{1+2n}}\sum_{m_2=0}^{n}\binom{2n-m_2}{m_2}\left(\frac{1}{4x^2y^2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)^{m_2}$$

Comment: I wonder if a approach similar to the question in the link would work? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950916/finding-the-2n1-th-derivative-of-fracy2n1xy1-x2y2-with-respect-t I trying to figure it out the answer though...