# What is the $n$ th derivative of $\ln(x)/(1+x^2)\:?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory, derivatives, closed-form

I'm into something but I came across the problem of finding a closed form for

$$\left( \frac{\ln x}{1+x^2} \right)^{(n)}$$

where the little $(n)$ denotes the $n$ th derivative of the function. After looking in some softwares, I believe the closed form is a rational function with $\ln x$ as a factor.

Thank for any help.

Edit: I found a way to change the problem above to this one:

$$ \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{(1-x)}{(1+x^2)(1-(1-x)y)}\right)^{(n)}$$

maybe this is easier?

EDIT $2$: I said closed formula but forgot to mention something easy to handle, and a summation like $\sum_{k=0}^n \cdots$ is hard, because after finding the derivative I'll need to find it's maximum...

A good example of what I mean [Finding the $2n+1$ th derivative of $\frac{y^{2n+1}xy}{1-x^2y^2}$ with respect to $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950916/finding-the-2n1-th-derivative-of-fracy2n1xy1-x2y2-with-respect-t)

I'm trying to establish the irrationality of a constant using Beuker's integrals, and using this approach you'll eventually need to find the $n$ th derivative of a function. In this case it can be either the first function or the second showed here. The $y$ in the second came from a substitution in the Beuker's integral.

Comment: What is $y$ in your Edit formula?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the denominator in powers of $x^2$?  Then find an explicit expression for $(x^k \ln x)^{(n)}$.  I've no idea where this is going though and whether the resulting series can be collapsed to something finite / explicit...

Comment: With CAS,For: `x>0 and n>1`: $$\frac{1}{4} \Gamma (n+1) \left((-x-i)^{-n-1} \left(-\left(\pi +2 i
   B_{\frac{x+i}{x}}(n+1,0)\right)\right)-(-x+i)^{-n-1} \left(\pi -2 i B_{\frac{x-i}{x}}(n+1,0)\right)\right)$$ where: $B$ is incomplete beta function.

Comment: @Pinteco : I added a representation in my other answer, it's as close as I can get it. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2):

If this can help,

$$(x^2+1)f(x)=\ln(x)$$

$$2xf(x)+(x^2+1)f'(x)=\frac1x$$

$$2f(x)+4xf'(x)+(x^2+1)f''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}$$

and more generally

$$(k+1)(k+2)f^{(k)}(x)+2(k+2)xf^{(k+1)}(x)+(x^2+1)f^{(k+2)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{x^{k+2}}.$$

Comment: How do you get that last step for all $k$?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts: can be obtained from Leibnitz rule, but I am afraid that the coefficients were/are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Leibniz rule
$\def\d{\frac{d^n}{dx^n}}$
$\def\cc#1{\left[#1 - \mathit{c.\!c.}\right]}$
$\def\lnn#1{\underline{\ln}_{#1}}$
$\def\Im{\operatorname{Im}}$
$\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$
$\def\im#1{\Im\left( #1 \right)}$

$$\begin{align}
(fg)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}\\
&=f^{(n)}g + \sum_{k=1}^n \binom n k f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}
\end{align}$$
for the product. For $n\geqslant1$, the $n$-th derivative of $g=\ln$ is:
$$
\d\ln x=(-1)^{n+1}\frac{(n-1)!}{x^n}
$$
From that we also get the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}$ as
$$
\d\frac1{x^2+1} = (-1)^n n! \Im{\frac{1}{(x-i)^{n+1}}}
$$
by noticing that
$$
\frac1{x^2+1}
= \frac{i}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+i} - \frac{1}{x-i}\right)
= \Im{\frac1{x-i}}
$$
Using the imaginary part only works for real $x$, and in the remainder I'll use $\Im$ assuming $x\in\mathbb R$.  For complex $x$ it's the same route, just more tedious to write down.  Plugging everything into Leibniz' rule, the binomial coefficients cancel out almost entirely and we get

$$
\d\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}
=(-1)^n n! \im{\frac{1}{(x-i)^{n+1}}
\left(
\ln x - \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k \left(1-i/x \right)^k
\right)}
$$

> Writing the sum as incomplete lower Natural logarithm
>   $$
> \lnn{n} x = -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k (1-x)^k
> $$
>   we get for $x\in\mathbb R$:
>   $$
> \d\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}
> =(-1)^n n! \Im \frac{\ln x + \lnn{n}(i/x)}{(x-i)^{n+1}}
> $$

Moreover, this gives an asymptotic formula for $|x|<1$ due to $\lnn{\infty}=\ln$:

$$
\d\frac{\ln x}{x^2+1} \approx
\Re \frac{(-1)^n n! \pi}{2(x-i)^{n+1}} \qquad\text{for large }n
$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the nth derivative of $ln(x)$ and $(1+x^2)^{(-1)}$ and then use Liebnitz's rule
$(fg)^{(n)}
= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$.

Comment: Computing the derivatives of $(1+x^2)^{-1}$ still isn't trivial: I could find a closed form using the composition of $f(x)=1+x^2$ and $g(x)=1/x$ and using Faà di Bruno's formula, but it still is a rather tedious. Do you have any simpler solution?

Comment: Or the other Leibnitz formula $(fg)^{(n)}= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} f^{(k)}g^{(n-k)}$

Comment: Oops. My mistake. Fixed and upvoted.